# Double bridge move in TSP

Tags: permutation, traveling-salesman

I want to implement the double bridge move in TSP. I know that I have to select 3 random positions and split the permutation into 4 parts and then I have to reconnect these parts together in different order, but I would like to get all possible combination that can be available for TSP problem by double bridge?

Assuming that the number of cities are n, so will all possible combination for double bridge be n?

Comment: I cannot understand a thing. Are you asking to write a complete solution for you or something (without so much as specifying the environment and tools, but that's off-topic anyway)? Or explain the double-bridge method in a way you can understand (then you need to at least demonstrate you've done your own research)?

Comment: @nbro Some googled links: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65610/double-bridge-moves-implementation-by-splitting-in-3-parts (your other question that likewise doesn't demonstrate any attempts to look into theory), http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/stochastic/iterated_local_search.html

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev If you don't know what I'm talking about, just don't blindly say something. I'm not talking about iterated local search. By the way, if you read carefully I'm asking for pseudocode, but not just that. Really, stop commenting around like if you were smart.

Answer (score 0):

If we try to divide the whole permutation into near about four equal parts and reconnect them to find new solution, then the approximate number of neighborhood solutions may be [(n-2)/4]^3 for n number of cities. Here, [x] represents the least integer value that is greater than or equal to x.